# "404 Not Found" error in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am using asp.net mvc 2.0. in that i am using partial views but whenever i clicked on particular link i get the follwing error

404 Not Found

can any one konw the solution the application run properly at local host but it shows the error when i uploaded on the server. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you generate the links? You should always use Html.ActionLink() or Url.Action() to generate links, to avoid problems when deploying.

For example, if you want to link to /Ctrl/Act/123 you should not use this:

```
<a href="/Crtl/Act/123">Here</a>
```

but this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Here", "Act", "Ctrl", new { id = ""}, new {}) %>
```

Comment: i am using
<a href="#" onclick="LoadPartialView('#MainContentDiv', '/Home/ClickMe')">Click Me</a><br />

Comment: So instead of "/Home/ClickMe" you should use Url.Action("ClickMe", "Home").

Comment: i want to calll java script on onclick event for that reson i am using <a> tag

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="LoadPartialView('#MainContentDiv', '<%=Url.Action("ClickMe", "Home")%>')">Click Me</a><br />

Comment: So which answer are you accepting, mine or the one by powtac? You have accepted his, but you have commented the other way around... you can undo your acceptance still. You should accept the answer that was most helpful, not the first one you see... You should press the arrow up too.

Comment: but i got another problem because of this my buttons are not working
<input type="button"  value="Add"  onclick="LoadPartialViewPost('#MainContentDiv', '/Home/ProductPage/<%= (id=catId) %>', $('form').serialize())" />

Comment: Same thing, you have a /Home/ProductPage/id url, you should replace it with a Url.Action call. Try with <%=Url.Action("ProductPage", "Home", new { id = catId})%>

Answer (score 0):

Check your servers error log. There must be 404 error details.

Open the [**network tab in FireBug**](http://getfirebug.com/network) reload the page and trigger the "wrong" request. And then check where the request goes to. FireBug catches all request a browser send.

Comment: When there is really nothing in the error log file, if could mean that your request is going fatally wrong to another url.

Comment: how can i get that wrong url because when i debug my application on local host it shows me correct url but when i upload it i get error.

Comment: I dont know why. BUT: 1. your browser (javascript) says 404. 2. Your server does not recognizes the request. Conclusion: the request goes maybe to an other target.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer to the following question worked for me:

[ASP.NET MVC2: Can't find controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105699/asp-net-mvc2-cant-find-controller)

Add IIS application wildcard mapping to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

[Installing Wildcard Application Mappings (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true)